# How can I restrict my computer's ability to connect to other ip's

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ip, ip-address

I have a comma seperated list of IP addresses in a text file like this:

```
192.xxx.xxx.xxx,213.www.www.www,255.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

Can I block my Ubuntu 19 from connecting to those IP addresses? If yes, How?

Comment: Using [`ufw`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/ufw.8.html) (the Uncomplicated FireWall), for example?

Comment: Write a script that updates the firewall rules in ufw or iptables directly to deny the traffic going in or out from/to those IPs

Comment: Install firewall. Yes of course you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, packet filters such as Linux iptables cannot block or allow traffic by hostname(s) or domain. Packet filters only understand IP addresses.

Secondly, FirewallD cannot filter outbound traffic, unless you hack it. Therefore you must simply use iptables.

You must first resolve all the hostnames contained in the list, to IP addresses. 
You can use this tool if you have hundreds or thousands of hostnames to resolve: 
http://domaintoipconverter.com/index.php

Then save the list of IP address to a file (list.txt for example)

```
$ cat list.txt
10.20.20.2
8.8.8.8
1.1.1.1
1.2.3.4
8.8.4.4
```

Then add the IP addresses to firewall rules using a simple script

**Red Hat / CentOS**

```
#!/bin/bash
# Stop and disable firewalld
systemctl stop firewalld
systemctl disable firewalld
yum clean all
yum install iptables-services -y
systemctl enable iptables
systemctl start iptables
# For loop statement that will read and add all the IPs from the list to firewall rule. 
for i in $(cat list.txt);
do 
iptables -A OUTPUT -d "$i" -j DROP
done
# Save the rules
service iptables save
```

**Debian / Ubuntu**

```
#!/bin/bash
apt-get update
apt install  iptables-persistent -y
# For loop statement that will read and add all the IPs from the list to firewall rule. 
for i in $(cat list.txt);
do 
iptables -A OUTPUT -d "$i" -j DROP
done
# Save the rules
netfilter-persistent save
netfilter-persistent reload
```

Verify the changes:

```
$ iptables -L
```